# ReactJS, the index of map function for the onClick event gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, array-map

I found a bug, but don't know why this is causing a bug like this.
Inisde a map function, for the onClick event, I gave an arrow function that refers to the index(`idx`) which is the argument of the map function. Why `idx` in this code gives me `undefined`? As of my understanding, due to the nature of closure, this `idx` should hold the value inside the map function. I've been thinking a long time to figure it out, but in vain.

```
import React from "react";

import styles from "./FileSelectionList.module.css";

function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2, k = 1024) {
    let i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k)); // log() in JS is Equivalent to ln() in Mathematics.
    if (i > 8) {
        bytes = 0;
    }
    return bytes === 0
        ? "0 Bytes"
        : parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(Math.max(0, decimals))) +
                " " +
                ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"][i];
}

const FileSelectionList = (props) => {
    if (props.selectedFiles.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    const changeFileHandler = (event) => {
        const idx = event.target.getAttribute("data-idx");
        const file = event.target.getAttribute("data-file");
        props.onChangeFile(idx, file);
    };

    // const removeFileHandler = (event) => {
    //   const idx = event.target.getAttribute("data-idx");
    //   props.onRemoveFile(idx);
    // };

    const removeFileHandler = (event, idx) => {
        console.log("idx:", idx);
        props.onRemoveFile(idx);
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles["file-selection-result"]}>
            <ul className={styles["file-info-list"]}>
                {props.selectedFiles.map((file, idx) => {
                    // console.log("file:", file);
                    // console.log("idx:", idx);
                    const id = Math.random().toString();
                    return (
                        <li key={id}>
                            <div className={styles["file-info-detail"]}>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>
                                        {idx + 1}. {file.name}
                                    </strong>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Size: {formatBytes(file.size, 2)}</strong>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles["buttons-container"]}>
                                <div className={styles["button-container"]}>
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        data-max-size="104857600"
                                        className={styles["file-change-btn"]}
                                        id={id}
                                        // onChange={changeFileHandler}
                                        // data-idx={idx}
                                        // data-file={file} // string // not a File object
                                        onChange={(event, idx, file) => {
                                            changeFileHandler(idx, file);
                                        }}
                                    ></input>
                                    <label htmlFor={id}>C</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className={styles["button-container"]}>
                                    <button
                                        className={styles["file-remove-btn"]}
                                        // onClick={removeFileHandler}
                                        // data-idx={idx}
                                        onClick={() => {
                      console.log(idx); // undefined <------ This is the cause of the bug.
                                            removeFileHandler(idx);
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        R
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles["thumbnail-container"]}>
                                <img
                                    className={styles["thumbnail"]}
                                    src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
                                    alt={file.name}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FileSelectionList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the bug is most likely introduced here

```
 <input
    type="file"
    data-max-size="104857600"
    className={styles["file-change-btn"]}
    id={id}
    // onChange={changeFileHandler}
    // data-idx={idx}
    // data-file={file} // string // not a File object
    onChange={(event, idx, file) => {
        changeFileHandler(idx, file);
    }}
```

/>

it uses the local varaible idx which is not likely provided by onChange

```
  // it should be
  onChange={(event) => changeFileHandler(idx, file)}
  // as (event, idx, ...) => { all params after event, could be undefined  }

    // try changing this
    const removeFileHandler = (event, idx) => {
        console.log("idx:", idx);
        props.onRemoveFile(idx);
    };

    //if event param is not used, try removing it

   const removeFileHandler = (idx) => {
        console.log("idx:", idx);
        props.onRemoveFile(idx);
    };
```

and try not using random no as index, use id or index as a last option,
cuz it will help with performance with large list,
and bugs could be introduced when ids are unstable

```
 const id = Math.random().toString();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was some misunderstanding in my knowledge. It was due to that unused local variable.